# Using fluent-ffmpeg with NodeJS to speed up converted video

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I'm using `require('fluent-ffmpeg')`  to convert a server side video. The only problem is that the input video is slowed down X2 (30fps, contains double frames) so I need the output video to be sped up X2.

The videoSpeed parameter doesn't seem to work. The inputFPS also didn't work (thought about giving it the value 60)

How do I speed up the output video?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found it under video filters:

ffmpeg('/path/to/file.avi')
.videoFilters('setpts=0.5*PTS')